# MySQL slashes and nl2br

Tags: php, mysql, newline, backslash

I am trying to store HTML posted from a textarea into a database.  I have a textarea inside a form which I have called "message".  The PHP code that processes it is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){         
            $title = stripslashes($title);
            $message = stripslashes($message);
        }

        $title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
        $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

        $q = "INSERT INTO table (title,datetime,text) VALUES ('{$title}',NOW(),'{$message}')";
        $rows_affected = $db->exec($q);
        if($rows_affected > 0){
            echo "<p>Done.</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>Failed. </p>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is then retrieving this and converting newlines to `<br />`.  Here is what I am doing:

```
$res = array();

$order = array("\r\n","\n","\r");
$replace = '<br />';

$q = "SELECT title,datetime,text FROM table";
$res = $db->get_all($q);
if($res){
    foreach($res as $result){
        $result['title'] = stripslashes($result['title']);
        $result['text'] = str_replace($order, $replace, stripslashes($result['text']));
    }       
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
```

I just can't get rid of those pesky `\r\n`'s in the message.  I have tried changing `$order` to

```
$order = array("\\r\\n","\\n","\\r");
// and even
$order = array("\\\r\\\n","\\\n","\\\r");
```

but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, same problem.  When that didn't work, that's when I switched to using the method above.  As far as I am aware, nl2br() only removes \n, not \r\n.

Comment: Oh, you've removed that question.  I was asked if I had used nl2br().

Comment: `nl2br()` adds `<br />` while retaining the (CR)LF (`\r`)`\n`.
Why would you worry about an extra `\r\n`?

You can keep newlines in your document without `<br />` using the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: nl2br() converts all combinations of \n and \r (\n, \r, \n\r and \r\n)

Comment: OK, but the problem is I want to replace these newlines entered in the textarea with `<br />`'s so that when I echo out the html, we have breaks where the person wants them.

Comment: Your method works fine for me, but personally I would use nl2br and then just strip off \r and \n. Also, you should never need to use stripslashes on data you've pulled *out* of the database. If you need to do this you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Ah I thought since `mysql_real_escape_string` adds slashes for inputting into the database that I would need to remove them when retrieving data.

Comment: I always apply nl2br just as I output. echo nl2br($data);

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string doesn't produce a result that stores the actual escape character in the database, it prepares the value to ensure that characters that need escaping will be stored correctly (eg a " in the value won't break the insert but will store the ", not \", in the database)... because they're not stored, they don't need removing on retrieval

Comment: OK, thanks.  I have removed calls to `stripslashes` and changed back to using `nl2br()`.  These CRLF's just aren't budging, there are no `<br />`'s anywhere.  Extremely annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($res = $db->get_all('SELECT title,datetime,text FROM table')){
    foreach ($res as &$result){
        $result['text'] = nl2br($result['text']);
    }       
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
```

I did three things:

- Remove the `stripslashes`. They mustn't be there. The slashes `mysql_real_escape_string` adds are removed when the query is executed.
- I used the function `nl2br` for the new lines. Why write something yourself if it's already built in?
- I added a `&` in front of `$result` in the `foreach` loop. If I didn't do this only the shallow copies were modified, not the variables themselves. Thus there wouldn't be any change at all.

Comment: "Furthermore I added a & in front of $result". BANG! That was the problem.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually you did 4 things: you left useless ` $result['title'] = $result['title'];` line in place :)

Answer (score 0):

For the retrieving of the data you don't need to screw around with str_replace/stripslashes.

```
$res = array();

$q = "SELECT title,datetime,text FROM table";
$res = $db->get_all($q);
if($res){
    foreach($res as &$result){
        $result['title'] = $result['title']; // Don't see the reason for stripslashes here
        $result['text'] = nl2br($result['text']);
    }       
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
```

Use nl2br to convert your \n to proper HTML line breaks. (Note: If you want to show the text inside of a textarea again, e.g. for editing, you need to output the "text" as-is). The only thing that you would want to do is use `strip_tags` to prevent HTML from being inserted into your output.

Comment: Whoops. True, I was too quick on that one.

Comment: An important point imo is that nl2br() adds "<br />" (or "<br>" if the second argument is false) to the string in front of "\r\n", or in front of any "\n" that isn't directly preceded by "\r" (as Lekensteyn also pointed out). It doesn't "convert your \n to proper HTML line breaks".

Answer (score 0):

more usual way of what nikic did

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row){
  $data[$key]['text'] = nl2br($row['text']);
}
```

you did overwrite your temporary $result variable, while you have to write modified variable back into array.
and give our variables sensible names.
Also, consider to use htmlspecialchars() if it's user supplied text.